# Commnication with scanner using Node js

Tags: node.js, usb

Is it possible to to communicate with scanner using node js     ?
We are using a php application which currently uses a Java applet to communicate with a scanner.
Since latest chrome versions have stopped support for applets we are looking for an alternative method for usb port communication
Can nodejs help us initiate the scan and read bufferstream from the port ?
If not what others options do we have ?

Comment: Why is this tagged with PHP when you're asking about nodejs?

Comment: What machine/OS are you running?

Comment: node.js runs on your web server, not on the user's computer when they visit your website.  The scanner is connected to the user's computer, right?  So you need to use something that can run on their computer.

Comment: The application is hosted in CentOS server but used by Windows installed client machines. @David : Nodejs can act as server on client machines.We are planning to install nodejs on client machines as the software will be used only in specific number of machines at  he client side

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible with additional libraries.
Try to use this one https://github.com/tessel/node-usb

Answer (score -1):

There is no pure javascript solution.

Fast way is to convert Java applet to Java Web Start. You have to write JNLP which download jars and runs applet outside browser.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/applet_migration.html

You can also install scanning daemon on client side and connect via web sockets.
Eg. https://www.npmjs.com/package/scanner-js